# Laravel eloquent selecting colms from third table using eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three Model `User` `Review` and `Product`. Product has a `hasMany` relation with `User` model. And `User` model has a `hasOne` relation with `Review` model.

But there is no relation between `Product` and `Review` Model. I am trying to select the products with users and want to select that user's rating from review model. Here is my code what I am trying to do..

```
 $product=new Product;
 $product->where('status', 1)
            ->with(array('user'=>function($query){
                $res=$query->select('id', 'userName', 'profilePic','firstName', 'lastName');
               /*$rating=Review::where('user_id',$res->id);*/ this doesn't work but may be I need something similar? 
            }))
            ->with('cocabeanconditioning')
            ->with('Image')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(9);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dot notation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), for example:

```
->with('user', 'user.review')
```

Comment: Nice. But how can I retrieved only one or two colms instead of returning all the colms?

Comment: @sadek click the link in my answer, scroll down a bit and read the `Eager Loading Specific Columns` section.

Answer (score 0):

You can select specific columns for relations like this:

```
$products = Product::with(['user'=>function($q){
            $q->select('users.id')->with(['review'=>function($q){
                $q->select('reviews.rating');
            }]);
        }])->get();
```